# Cannot upload file in Safari using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I cannot upload file using Win7+Safari using `ng-file-upload` in Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
   <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}"  ng-model="mul.image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="onFileSelect1($index);">
<img ngf-thumbnail="mul.image" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.image !=null">
</div>
```

Here I can not display image after selecting from drive. Here I need when user will select image it should display in image tag. It's working in all browsers except Win7+Safari well.

Comment: Did you checked the console of safari for any errors?

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty : Yes,i am getting this `undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'FileAPI.readAsDataURL(a,d)')
/js/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js:2
` error in console.

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty : Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Have you looked in the issues section of the library? https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty : i have also reported one issue there. [see here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1672).This is reportted by me.But they are unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a rights to this file? Mayby this is why you cant access to them?

What is your upload server side? Any code?

Comment: You are talking about which file. Using the above code i can preview the image first then i am going for upload.BTW i am using PHP for server side code.

Comment: I'm talking about uploaded file. Did you see this example page?
http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ 
Look at the source code mayby this help you.

Comment: Karczewskai : i checked this demo page in win=safari,its also not working.its throwing this `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'FileAPI.readAsDataURL(file, listener)')
http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js:415` error.

Comment: Any update? I am having the exact same issue on Safari on the lane 415